# how to align the text box at center of navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In the link below:

http://bootply.com/69899

You can see that the input text box is left aligned in the navbar. Is there any way I can align it at the center of the navbar (both horizontally and vertically)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="brand" href="#">Test</a>
      <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
      <input type="url" placeholder="none">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Worked fine for me. Considering you are using bootstrap.

Comment: Not working, text box is not aligning to the center of the navbar. You can edit the html directly at http://bootply.com/69899

Comment: @razorwender What browser are you using? I tried it with chrome-27 and FF-21. Both showed the textbox left aligned.

Comment: @KrishnaSrinivas I think it's your computer, I'm viewing it with google chrome no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Setting line-height to your div height and using the common align-center should help.